# Using Hashing to count the number of occurrences of a pattern within an integer array

Tags: optimization, integers, hashing, intervals

So I have a problem that is ,I have an integer array and first I define an interval as a good interval iff, within the interval every integer appears an even (including zero) number of times. I want to find the number of good intervals in a given integer array. For example, if array = [7, 7, 1, 5, 5, 1], the good intervals are [1, 2], [3, 6], [4, 5], [1, 6] corresponding to the contiguous subarrays [7, 7], [1, 5, 5, 1], [5, 5], [7, 7, 1, 5, 5, 1]. If array = [4, 5, 6, 5, 4], then there are no good intervals.

I have a naive solution which would be to use 2 for loops and check for every possible interval whether there is a good interval but this takes O(n^2) time. I want to find a better solution that runs in O(nlogn) time and I feel that using hashing may give me a faster solution, the problem is I do not know how to incorporate it into my answer. I have been reading up on the rolling robin-karp hashing algorithm to give me some ideas but I think that this algorithm is not applicable to what I seek. Do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: What's the context where you encountered this problem?  Can you credit the original source?

Comment: The problem is from a homework assignment so I don't think I can give you a link to it. I have transposed the problem from the source to here as good as I can. Is there some missing information that you want to clarify?